# WP Crowdfunding login redirect fails

Tags: plugins, authentication

I am using wp crowdfunding plugin for my website but when I create a campaign the campaigns are visible in the dashboard but are not found in the wpcf_list and the another problem is that when I login as a user after successful login I am redirected to some page id every time which says page not found
To reproduce the issue you can use clubblocks theme, wp crowdfunding plugin, woocommerce plugin, and colorlib login customizer.

I don't if this is helpful but I am willing to provide any further info that is required to resolve the issue

Comment: You'll have to ask the plugin's support team about this. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here. (Also, if you need to add context or information to your question, please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/424117/edit) instead of posting it as a comment.)

Comment: Your question, while understandable, is too broad. There are just too many plugins for a WordPress Development Q&A to cover them all. Unless you want help digging into the code, I think you would be better off asking the plugin author.

Comment: Yeah I did that but the issue was fixed when I installed another crowdfunding plugin alongside wp crowdfunding